# Как запустить калькулятор, при введении числа в input (пример кода внутри)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Написал простой калькулятор, после того как вставляю в него число, он не производит никаких операций, пока я не кликну по пустому месту.

Нет ли способа выводить результат сразу, как только я впишу оба числа. Может быть, есть способ запустить калькулятор на события клавиатуры как нибудь? подскажите как реализовать?

(кажется есть, только что обратил внимание, что когда ввожу сюда текст, он транслируется внизу при этом не нужно кликать мышью)

```js
$('.first,.second').change(function() {
  var a = parseInt($('.first').val());
  var b = parseInt($('.second').val());

  c = a * b;

  if (!c) {
    $('.result').val('0');
  } else {
    $('.result').val(c);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='first' placeholder="введите число">
<input class='second' placeholder="введите число">
<input class='result' readonly="readonly" placeholder="рузультат">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас слушается событие `change`, которое не происходит, пока `<input>` не потеряет фокус.

Другое дело – HTML5 [событие "input"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input):

```js
$('.first,.second').on('input', function() {
  var a = parseInt($('.first').val());
  var b = parseInt($('.second').val());

  c = a * b;

  $('.result').val( c ? c : '0');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='first' placeholder="первое число">
<input class='second' placeholder="второе число">
<input class='result' readonly="readonly" placeholder="произведение чисел">
```

Comment: не подскажите русскоязычную статью, где о всех событиях можно почитать, а то  полгода пишу и все новые узнаю.

Comment: как раз добавил только что ссылку на описание события, но на английском. На MDN перечислены, наверное, все события.